# Datasource Establishment in Tableau and 170,000 records

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

I have two EXCEL datasources. 175,000 rows. I'm trying to set up a join (Add New Join Clause) using the INNER option between the two datasources. The left datasource includes certain member id #s. Unfortunately, the right datasource's member id #s are within a large field called member Desc. Something like below,

**Datasource Left**
***Member ID #***
*ALL89098*

**Datasource Right**
***Member Desc*** 
YTRNNN TO=*ALL89098_KIA TO BE OR NOT* OR
PO*ALL89098 JOE*

So, I need to deal with two scenarios as you notice from above. The member id is within the Member Desc after a TO= and it could be anywhere like scenario 2 POALL89098

If I can't get this done in Tableau to establish the Join between these two columns from different datasources, since I have both of these datasources loaded into SQL Server DB, I can run SQL statements in SQL since they are in two different Tables within SQL Server DB as well.

I'm trying the use of CONTAINS clause in Tableau such as below but it is running very very slow. it is only Tableau Desktop with 16 GB Ram.

if contains([Member Desc],([Member id #])then
[Member id #]
ELSE
"NOT FOUND"
END

Thanks so much for your time.

SO, IS THERE A WAY TO HAVE THE REGEXP WITHIN IF AND ELSE OR CASE STATEMENTS?

Comment: You said your data sources are Excel but you tagged the question with Sql Server. Where does SQL Server fit in all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a join calculation. The highlighted dropdown shows where this can be found:

[image]

As long as the format of the Member ID in [Member Desc] has some pattern, it can be extracted with Regex. As you mention in your question, one way the ID may present itself is after a "TO=" and it looks like it ends before a "_". The following regex calculated field will pull the string between the two:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([Member Desc],"([^TO=]*)(?=_)")
```

[image]

The result should properly join the two datasources:

[image]

The above is an outline which I hope sets you on the right path. I realize that there may be a few different methods in which the [Member ID] presents itself so I wont be able to nail down the exact Regex, but if there is any pattern at all then the format above should work. (ie: even if the only pattern is that [Member ID] is three letters followed by four numbers - or it always starts with an A and ends with something else - etc.)

Regex should also perform better than a contains() function, but do be aware that the function does need to search through every string in every row to make the join.

**Edit in response to comment:**

To add multiple conditions, try the following method:

```
IF LEN(REGEXP_EXTRACT([Member Desc],"([^FROM=]*)(?=,)")) > 0
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Member Desc],"([^FROM=]*)(?=,)")
ELSEIF LEN(REGEXP_EXTRACT([Member Desc],"([^TO=]*)(?=,)")) > 0
THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT([Member Desc],"([^TO=]*)(?=,)")
ELSEIF [...Put as many of these as might match your pattern]
THEN [...Put as many of these as might match your pattern]
END
```

Essentially the calculation is going down the list and trying each possibility. I changed yours a little to look at the length (LEN()) of the returned value which should compare fairly quickly, as it is an integer. As this calculation iterates through each ELSEIF and finds a match, it will stop iterating through the list -- so its important to put the most likely match at the top. The result of the calculated field should be a member ID. If there is no match, there really isn't a need for an ELSE statement because the Inner Join will exclude it automatically.

**Edit in response to comment:**
Thank you. I see your recommendations.

Comment: So, if I need to put it in multiple conditions like below, do you know how the sentix could work. for example using an if and else condition. if REGEXP_EXTRACT([Member Desc],"([^FROM=]*)(?=,)") <> "0"then
REGEXP_EXTRACT([Member Desc],"([^TO=]*)(?=,)")
else
"NONE FOUND"
END

Comment: See edit to answer to hopefully answer your question. I think you were close to the right answer there, but I changed your IF portion to include LEN() as the conditional operator. I also removed the ELSE clause only because the Inner Join will do that for you if nothing is found.

Comment: Thank you. I used Case Statement for this purpose and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to find a way to strip out the member ID from the member desc in SQL. There should be some pattern to Member ID.
For instance is it always 3 letters followed by 5 numbers or something similar.
If you can come up with a pattern, then you can use SQL and some combination of Substring, Charindex, and/or Like %Text% or a regex
pattern to strip out the actual member ID in the SQL Server table as its own field before bringing it into Tableau.

Comment: Thank you so much!